# How to install multiple versions of XAMPP?

Tags: xampp

I'm having trouble installing multiple versions of XAMPP on my machine. I am currently using version **1.7.7** and installed it in **`/opt/lampp`**, but I also need to install the previous version which is version **1.7.1**. So I downloaded and installed version **1.7.1** in **`/opt/lampp2`**.

But when I run `/opt/lampp2/lampp start`command to start **1.7.1** version, why does XAMPP show that the version that is currently running is **1.7.7**, when it should be  **1.7.1**?

Comment: You should call it "XAMPP for Linux" to avoid confusion with LAMP.

Comment: is that way we need you put some code as example on the aswers! ALL links are DOWN!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is have separate directories and create a sym link to `/opt/lampp`

Keep **1.7.7** as **/opt/lampp.1_7_7** and **1.7.1** as **/opt/lampp.1_7_1** you can create a sym link to `/opt/lampp`. Based on the version choice you can change the sym link.

But the pain is if you have to switch versions you have delete the link and recreate a new one. So to avoid this, I found a script that can do the job.

Refer to [<s>this article</s>](http://www.jamesbrice.com/multiple-xampp-versions) (dead link, [web.archive.org backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919143637/http://www.jamesbrice.com/multiple-xampp-versions)) to create the sym link

[Script](http://www.jamesbrice.com/swap-lampp-script-download)  can help you to:

> - gives a choice of available versions of XAMPP (based on folder names
>     containing them, based on the pattern shown above),
> - stops the XAMPP
>     server processes,
> - deletes the existing lampp soft link,
> - creates a new
>     soft link pointing at the folder containing the the chosen version of
>     XAMPP.
>
> [Source](http://www.jamesbrice.com/multiple-xampp-versions)

Comment: is that way we need you put some code as example on the aswers! ALL links are DOWN!

Comment: links are not working anymore

Comment: @devav2 asking for register and login to get the answer. This answer should contain code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the idea to create a link, I try to make this works.
Remember that I am not a pro, I was looking for a solution and make this script to my self and share with you.

Just to future questions if you want to install 2 versions of xampp on Linux you have to install: Example:
xampp php5 on `/opt/lampp`  then rename it to /opt/lampp5, then do the same with the php7 bin installer (or tar) and rename it to /opt/lampp7.
then copy this code into a new `script.sh` file, make it writable `chmod +x script.sh`, then run it `$ ./script.sh` or `$ ./script.sh 5 start`
here is the code example running fine on ubuntu 16.04, its just a simple script to make it work on this kind of problem, since on windows we can do it at the installation steps.

```
#!/bin/bash

LAMPP_VERSION=$1
LAMPP_ACTION=$2

LAMPP="/opt/lampp"
XAMPP=$LAMPP"/xampp"

function stopall {
    sudo $XAMPP stopapache
    sudo $XAMPP stopmysql
}

function startall {
    sudo $XAMPP startapache
    sudo $XAMPP startmysql
}

function stopmysql {
    sudo $XAMPP stopmysql
}

function stopapache {
    sudo $XAMPP stopapache
}

function startmysql {
    sudo $XAMPP startmysql
}

function startapache {
    sudo $XAMPP startapache
}

function checklampplink {

    # check if exist a link and delete it
    if [[ -L "$LAMPP" && -d "$LAMPP" ]]
        then
            echo "$LAMPP is a symlink to a directory: try DELETE!"
            sudo rm -f $LAMPP
        else
            echo "NO $LAMPP LINK WAS FOUND!"
    fi

    # create a new link
    echo "try to create LAMPP link ..."
    cd /opt
    ln -s "$LAMPP$LAMPP_VERSION" "lampp"

    ## check if is created
    if [[ -L "$LAMPP" && -d "$LAMPP" ]];
        then
            echo $LAMPP "created!"
        else
            echo "LINK not created! exit 1"
            exit 1
    fi
}

function checkservices {

    # check if services exists and try to stop property
    PIDS_MYSQL=$(ps -C mysqld -C mysqld_safe -o pid=)
    PIDS_APACHE=$(ps -C /opt/lampp/bin/ -o pid=)

    if [ -n $PIDS_MYSQL ];
        then
            stopmysql
        else
            echo "NO MYSQL TO KILL"
    fi
    if [ -n "$PIDS_APACHE" ];
        then
            stopapache
        else
            echo "NO APACHE TO KILL"
    fi

}

### begin ###



####
# get an action
if [ -z $LAMPP_ACTION ];
    then
        echo
        echo "ACTION: ( start | stop | restart)?"
        read LAMPP_ACTION
    else
        echo "ACTION SET TO: "$LAMPP_ACTION
fi
# if action is stop exit
if [ "$LAMPP_ACTION" == "stop" ];
    then
        stopall
        exit 0
fi

####
# get a version
if [ -z $LAMPP_VERSION ];
    then
        echo
        echo "VERSION: ( 5 | 7 )? "
        read LAMPP_VERSION
     else
        echo "VERSION SET TO: " $LAMPP_VERSION
fi
if [[ "$LAMPP_VERSION" = "5" || "$LAMPP_VERSION" = "7" ]];
    then
        echo "GOOD version continue ..."
    else
        echo "Wrong version exit 1"
        exit 1
fi

## if action is start or restart do the same
checkservices

# check folder link
checklampplink

echo

echo "Select an option to START:"
echo "1) ALL current installed services on xampp"
echo "2) Apache and Mysql - phpmyadmin"
echo
echo "Type enter to start option default ( 1 ) "
read USER_START
echo
echo "Starting services ..."
echo

if [ -z $USER_START ];
    then
        startapache
        startmysql
     else
        if [ "$USER_START" = "1" ];
            then
                startall
            else
                startapache
                startmysql
        fi
fi

echo "Done";
exit 0
```

if this code have any syntax problem, sorry I just paste here.
good luck!

Comment: https://github.com/rafaelphp/lampp_switcher

Comment: ./script.sh 5 start
ACTION SET TO: start
VERSION SET TO:  5
GOOD version continue ...
./script.sh: line 67: [: 6557: binary operator expected
NO MYSQL TO KILL
NO APACHE TO KILL
NO /opt/lampp LINK WAS FOUND!
try to create LAMPP link ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'lampp': Permission denied
LINK not created! exit 1
getting error like this.

Comment: @rahul did u run it as root or using sudo? check you opt folder permission

Comment: ya i have done that. FYI i'm using linuxlite 4.4 based on ubuntu 18.04 version

Comment: @rahul can u list your opt lamp folders? should be like lampp56, lampp70, then try to create a link manually, `sudo ln -s /opt/lampp56 /opt/lamp`

Comment: i created the link with this comman `sudo ln -s /opt/lampp53 /opt/lamp`, and did `sudo /opt/lamp start`. Gives me error `sudo: /opt/lamp: command not found`

Comment: do u make the sh script executable? `sudo chmod +x lampp_switcher.sh`

Comment: pls rename the link with 2 p from lamp to lampp

Comment: Yes i did both of ur above methods. But still the prblm exists.